# Access DBF tables with ORM Eloquent in Laravel 5

Tags: php, eloquent

I need to configure Laravel 5 to use ODBC accessing Visual FoxPro tables through Eloquent ORM. 
I have tried inserting the following entry in the 'connections' list of 'database.php' file, but the application returns the error "Unsupported driver [odbc]":

```
'odbc' => [
    'driver' => 'odbc',
    'dsn' => 'Visual FoxPro Database',
    'database' => '',
],
```

Is there a way to use ODBC to access VFP tables, like I did using PHP flat application? Every help will be appreciated.

Comment: I found a way to access FoxPro tables with MariaDB Server using ENGINE=CONNECT. Through MySql WorkBench I can insert, update, delete rows on existing DBF tables. Following tutorial [https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/quickstart] with that configuration for the App, it works because i can insert rows in 'tasks' table, but the page doesn't show the column 'Name' value. Trying do delete a row i get the error "MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:". Is there someone knows restrictions or rules on Laravel using tables for that configuration.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Laravel 5 indicates that it supports the following database systems: MySQL, Postgres, SQLite, and SQL Server.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database

You could try installing the next library,
https://github.com/luads/php-xbase